# How to remove one file of selected files from input?

Tags: javascript, html

How to remove one file of selected files from input file control using javascript?

This is the input field:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="images" accept="image" id="images" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. HTML file input does not allows you to manipulate it's values for security reasons. As you can see here on [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) class which holds the HTML file input files does not have any methods to manipulate it. Simply it's a read-only class. But if you really want to do that, You can insert files to an array by iterating FileList class then you can remove the file from it. But keep in mind you can't set the modified value back to the input. So you can use multiple hidden inputs with base64 encoded file values or Ajax file upload